# Joomla - Argument 4 passed to JPluginHelper::importPlugin()

Tags: joomla

I'm trying to update my Joomla installation from 2.5.28 to 3.3.6 but I get a blank screen. There's an error in my error_log file stating "PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 4 passed to JPluginHelper::importPlugin() must be an instance of JEventDispatcher"... Any ideas will be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had issues with that as well. One of my plugins was not compatible with Joomla 3.0. What I recommend is unpublish all of your plugins and components that you installed and then one by one publish them and test the page. The one that breaks it probably needs to be updated.

Also take a look at your template to make sure that it is compatible with the joomla 3.0 standards.